# Reading data from server script using URL

Tags: iphone, string, nsurlrequest

I am calling a login script on the server using http call from iphone.
the script returns a string "Invalid" or "valid" based on given username/pswd.

Here is what I am using:

NSString *myurlstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/iph/login.aspx?username=%@&password=%@",uname,pswd];
  NSString *resultstr = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myurlstr] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

NSLog(@"HERE IS THE ONE: %@",resultstr);

Here is what the Console log prints:

> TestingTrying[51514:207] HERE IS THE ONE: Invalid Login/Password
>
> !DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
>
> html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
>
> head>title>
>    Untitled Page
>
> /title>/head>
>
> body>
>
> form name="form1" method="post" action="login.aspx?username=abc&password=abc" id="form1">
>
> input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJNzgzNDMwNTMzZGTnVSKZt+HQfSlQeCketelC9X+47A==" />
>
> div>
>
> /div>
>   /form>
>   /body>
>   /html>

Can someone help on how to get the string only(Invalid Login/Password) and not the content that starts from DOCTYPE onwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your simply asking how to get the first line from your server response, use a tokenizer. [This](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1777581) should point you in the right direction, just use new line which is /n from memory as the delimiter.